# Find associated BUs for a user in Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, marketingcloudapi, sfmc-business-unit

Is there an automated way to find out all the associated BUs for a user? Using SSJS or SOAP API or AMPscript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Niko has a good find when mentioning the undocumented SOAP object `AccountUserAccount`. It will be the key to finding all the associated BUs for a specific user.

In the code below, I used WSProxy library making a simple version for this. From what I observed, you can even run it in a child BU:

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.1");

var userName = "YOUR USERNAME"

var cols = ["Account.ID", "Account.Name"];
var filter = {Property: "AccountUser.UserID", SimpleOperator: "equals", Value: userName}

// Create a WSProxy object
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
var data = prox.retrieve("AccountUserAccount", cols, filter);

if (data.Results.length > 0) {
    Write("This username <b>" + userName + "</b> is associated with these following BUs:<br>")
    for (var i=0; i < data.Results.length; i++ ) {
        var BU_name = data.Results[i].Account.Name;
        var mid =  data.Results[i].Account.ID;
        Write("BU: " + BU_name + " | MID: " + mid + "<br>");
    }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct or easy approach on mapping Users and Business Units, yet there is still a way:

---

[Account](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/account.html) SOAP Object can help us with some useful properties but it is simply fully not retrievable.

[image]

---

[AccountUser](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/accountuser.html) SOAP Object is retrievable this time and also has a "AssociatedBusinessUnits" property but particularly that property is not, thus won't give the list of Business Units assigned for a User.

---

Nevertheless, there is an undocumented SOAP object named "AccountUserAccount" that helps us out. It works as a bridge between Users and Business Units. Please use the object at your own risk because  it might stop to be supported at any time. Now, to have a full solution you would need:

1. Do a retrieve on [AccountUser](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/accountuser.html) Object to get the info about all Users.
2. Per each User do a retrieve on the "AccountUserAccount" Object filtering by the "AccountUserId" parameter that you would have from the previous step. We need to apply a filter because the request usually times out due to the heavy response with all combinations of Users and Business Units (of course depends on how many of each you have on your account).
3. Do a retrieve on [BusinessUnit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/businessunit.html) Object to get more info about Business Units.

That is how you can have a holistic view of your Users and Business Units.

Answer (score 0):

This would be possible via SOAP using Retrieve on the [AccountUser Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/accountuser.html).

But the fields available are limited and discussed on IdeaExchange to make these available [here](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdXd3UAF/retrieve-associated-business-units-on-accountuser-via-soap-api)